# Creating custom function to change row & col names for a dataframe in RStudio; wont run as expected

Tags: r, dataframe

Beginner R user here.  I am practicing making my own functions, and I thought to make something that would reduce time in renaming rows/columns for my saved dataframes.  Below is what I came up with:

```
data.change.rowcolnames <- function(datainenv, namerows, namecols) {
    row.names(datainenv) <- namerows 
    colnames(datainenv) <- namecols
}
```

Basically, "datainenv" is the named dataframe, "namerows"/"namecols" are the vectors that contain all my intended row/col names.

Here is the code I tried to run with the funtion above:

```
data.change.rowcolnames(inflam_01, inflam_01_pats, inflam_01_days)
```

When I run it, it doesn't change the row/col names.  However, when I run the `row.names()` and `colnames()` functions on their own, they do.

Here is everything that I had to set it up, it's just some sample data for patient inflammation (no HIPAA violations!  its all fake...)

```
inflam_01 <- read.csv("inflammation-01.csv", header = F) #can't attach file...but the dataframe was created correctly and I can see all the data.
```

Used a unique id function I found online to help generate random patient IDs:

```
   create_unique_ids <- function(n, seed_no = 2, char_len = 5){
  set.seed(seed_no)
  pool <- c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9) #sets the parameters for what the ID will contain
  
  res <- character(n) # pre-allocating vector is much faster than growing it
  for(i in seq(n)){
    this_res <- paste0(sample(pool, char_len, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
    while(this_res %in% res){ # if there was a duplicate, redo
      this_res <- paste0(sample(pool, char_len, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
    }
    res[i] <- this_res
  }
  res
}
```

Used that function to generate 60 ids for the below vector:

```
inflam_01_pats <- c(create_unique_ids(60, 2, 10)) #used a function example for the "create_unique_ids";
```

Created a vector with the numbers 1-40 for the "day names"

```
inflam_01_days <- c(1:40)
```

Added it all together and it appears to work, as it doesn't show an error message...but the default column/row names are still in the `inflam_01` dataframe...

Comment: Does it work if you use `inflam_01  <- data.change.rowcolnames(inflam_01, inflam_01_pats, inflam_01_days)`?

Comment: the last line of the function should be `datainenv` or `return(datainenv)`

Comment: as mentioned by rawr, R returns the result of the last line in a function (aside from specific break conditions). Thus what you get back is the result of `colnames(datainenv) <- namecols`.  With `return(datainenv)` you return the changed object.

Comment: ok, that makes sense.  I've gotten it to work that way.  But now if just spits it out in the console.  How do I get it to save the new object in my environment? Under a new name?

Comment: I found a workaround, but it's not as streamlined as I would have hoped... I uused `inflam_01_named <<- data.change.rowcolnames(inflam_01, inflam_01_pats, inflam_01_days)` and that created a new df in my environment.  However, do y'all know how I could do this within the function itself (providing the new name of the output as an arguement)?

Comment: Jon Spring: i just realized that you had already led me in that direction...  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Either:

```
inflam_01_named <<- data.change.rowcolnames(inflam_01, inflam_01_pats, inflam_01_days)
```

or

```
inflam_01_named <- data.change.rowcolnames(inflam_01, inflam_01_pats, inflam_01_days)
```

worked.  Thanks for the help!